# What layout should I use if I'm going to place 60 (more in the future) images in a grid-like layout?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, layout, grid

I need them to be ordered neatly and be able to use animations on each image.

The animation will be a simple "grow" effect to symbolize that the image has been selected. So when a user clicks the image, that Image will grow a bit.

So, a grid? A stack? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **WrapPanel** might be one possible choice. This will avoid you having to pre-determine the number of columns of images, making that flexible depending on available width.

When an image is selected, you could simply modify its RenderTransform temporarily to increase the scale factor, which will make it *grow a bit* without affecting the other images around it.